# Having Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of argument list in EF core while inserting data to SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

this is the query which I am running. when I run this query directly in sql it works fine. how to make it successful in EF Core without exception

**I know there is some data in query causing this. I simply want to disable this validation**

```
INSERT INTO public."RxOrder"("OrderId","OrderControl","RxAssignedId","OrderStatus","OrderDateTime","doctorFirstName","doctorLastName","doctorDEA","OrderEffectiveDate","OrderCode","ResidentId","MedicationId","Comments","CommentsSource","OrderBy","CreatedBy","CreatedOn","LastModifiedBy","LastModifiedOn","FillerOrderControl","IsRequestSent","ErrorCode","IsError","MessageControlId","ErrorText","SentHL7Message","IsAckRecieved","Ack","IsResultRecieved","RecievedHL7Message","NAck","OrderTo","DosageForm","DosageUnits","TotalDispensedAmount","TotalDispensedUnits","TotalNoOfRefills","RefillsRemaining","FillNumber","ActualDispensedAmount","ActualDispensedUnits","ActualRefillsRemaining","ActualStrength","ActualStrengthUnit","RxNumber","IsRecieved","OrderUpdatedTheMed","UpdationDone") 
Values(108614,'RF','GOL2\F\134788\F\3145',NULL,NULL,'Sandra','Nettina','','6/24/2016 7:40:18 PM','RX',NULL,101227,NULL,NULL,'iCM',2163,'6/24/2016 7:40:18 PM',NULL,NULL,NULL,False,NULL,True,'16062419401877',NULL,'<div>MSH|^~\&amp;|ICM|9QPF|FrameworkLTC|PCP|20160624194019||OMP^O09^OMP_O09|16062419401877|P|2.5||||||ASCII|||</div><div>PID|1|4361|||Weisenmiller^Anna^^^^^D||19270823|F|||1811 Albert Rill Road^^Hampstead^MD^21074||(410)239-4200||||||215-26-7551|||||||||||N|||||||||</div><div>PV1|1|I|^^^9QPF^^^^||||^Nettina^Sandra |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||20160506||||||||</div><div>ORC|RF|108614|GOL2\F\134788\F\3145||||||20160624|||^Nettina^Sandra |||20160624||||||Albert Rill Road|1811 Albert Rill Road^^Hampstead^MD^21074|(410)239-4200|||||||</div><div>TQ1|1|^EA|||||20160617||R||TAKE ONE TABLET BY MOUTH IN THE EVENING|||</div><div>RXO|00555083205^WARFARIN TAB |||||||||||||||||||^^||||||||</div><div>NTE|1|P||PI</div><div>EVN|O09|20160624194019|||||9QPF</div>',False,'',False,NULL,'<div>MSH|^~\&amp;|FrameworkLTC|PCP|ICM|9QPF|20160624194120||ACK^O09^ACK|16062419401877|P|2.5||||||ASCII|||</div><div>MSA|AE|16062419401877||||</div><div>ERR|||207|||||Unable to cast COM object of type ''DrugUtil.CDrugPriceClass'' to interface type ''DrugUtil._CDrugPrice''. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID ''{24265817-C356-4070-B2E0-8594095C15F0&#125;'' failed due to the following error: Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)).||||</div>','FLTC',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'249009',False,False,NULL)
```

Comment: So, we have a single query, that we cannot execute, that by itself will not generate such an error message. You really need to learn to produce an [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so issue was character **{** I found by myself
I just fixed it temporarily by replacing it with `&#123` html hexa based character